# Symfony, No Authentication Provider found for token of class UsernamePasswordToken after login, how to?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, authorization

I have a `loginAction` where I attempt to get a user from the db and log her in.

It seems that the 'main' firewall rules are used rather than the `secure_area` ones. because i get:

`No Authentication Provider found for token of class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken"`

if i add

```
guard:
        authenticators:
            - token_authenticator
```

to the 'main' firewall rule, then the error goes away, but the `token_authenticator`takes over and I get `Authentication Required` on all routes

If I dump the `$token` or the `session` after I login, I can see my user in there.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('entity.user');

        $hasEmail = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy([
            'email'    => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
        ]);

        // if credentials found
        if ($hasEmail) {
            // login the user
            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($hasEmail, $hasEmail->getPassword(), "secure_area", $hasEmail->getRoles());
            $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);
            $this->get('session')->set('_security_secure_area', serialize($token));


            //$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
            //$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
        } else {
            $error = 'invalid credentials';
        }
    }

    return [];
}
```

here are my firewall rules:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
        provider: db_provider

    main:
        anonymous: ~

    secure_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - token_authenticator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firewalls` are differentiated by the set of `pattern` which is the prefix of your route parameter. So, in your case, `secure_area` will ever be reached as the `main` firewall will takeover.

You can use any unique pattern like `/secured` or `/api` to reach out the firewall when you use a route with similar pattern.

Moreover, You shouldn't handle the user login explicitly unless required. Instead you should use `$authenticationUtils`. Please follow [this document(for 2.8)](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/form_login_setup.html).

Setting up `providers` and `firewalls` in `security.yml` is depends on source of Users who can login to the application. This will be bit clear once you mention about those.

Hope this helps!